# app/uninstalled Webhook Registered but not showing in /webhooks.json

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

So basically I followed the below steps:

1. Make a call using PHP for app/uninstalled. Check my code.

   ```
   $chh = curl_init();

   $params = [
     'webhook' => [
     'topic' => 'app/uninstalled',
     'address' => 'https://example.herokuapp.com/delete.php',
     'format' => 'json'  
     ]
   ];

   $json_string_params = json_encode($params);

   $headers = array(
     'X-Shopify-Access-Token:'.$access_token,
     'Content-Type:application/json'
   );

   curl_setopt($chh, CURLOPT_URL, 
   'https://example.myshopify.com/admin/webhooks.json');
   curl_setopt($chh, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($chh, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
   curl_setopt($chh, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
   curl_setopt($chh, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_string_params);
   curl_setopt($chh, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

   $resultt = curl_exec($chh);

   $final = json_decode($resultt);
   ```
2. I'm getting below response:

> stdClass Object
>   (
>       [webhook] => stdClass Object
>           (
>               [id] => 475440480367
>               [address] => https://example.herokuapp.com/delete.php
>               [topic] => app/uninstalled
>               [created_at] => 2019-01-18T05:04:20-05:00
>               [updated_at] => 2019-01-18T05:04:20-05:00
>               [format] => json
>               [fields] => Array
>                   (
>                   )
>               [metafield_namespaces] => Array
>                   (
>                   )
>           )
>   )

3. Then, I'm calling this:

`https://example.myshopify.com/admin/webhooks.json`

but this will give me null that you haven't registered anything yet.

Comment: Are you passing `X-Shopify-Access-Token` while accessing `https://example.myshopify.com/admin/webhooks.json` ?

Comment: @RajKumar Hello buddy, Yes I'm getting a response in Postman with attaching access_token. But now I want to receive webhook when an app is uninstalled

Comment: you will receive webhook at your registered url when app gets uninstalled. You need to make sure that your end point is https enabled and accepts post request.

Comment: @RajKumar Okay do you have any related code for it. Because the verify code from Shopify doc doesn't work with me.